# Issues iterating through strings and caesar shifting up and down at the same time

Tags: python, python-3.x

so I'm making a cipher and I want a program to easily encrypt and decrypt messages with this cipher, only issue is, I'm relatively new to Python and am not very good at this highly advanced stuff. I'm focusing on the encryption process right now. I've made a short guide on how to encrypt messages in this cipher in this document:
[Cipher](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1iPsBWJobyLTjuhxVAz68fGmIlcprLGFL4yKeTPBwZEk/edit?usp=sharing)

I am having trouble finding a way to iterate through the individual characters in the string, shifting even characters down and odd ones up by the catalyst, and making the first character of each new word odd regardless of its placement in the string (and shifting numbers) all at the same time. I have the catalyst changing, reversing of the string, etc working just fine, it's just the actual encryption part that's giving me issues.

Here is my code so far:

```
# MTBE stands for Message To Be Encrypted
# Getting Catalyst
catalyst = int(input("Catalyst: "))
# The message to encrypt
mtbe = input("Message to encrypt: ")
# Reversing each word in the message
new_mtbe_one = reverseWordSentence(mtbe)
print(new_mtbe_one)

# Actual encrypting
catalyst_reset = 6
#
# Iteration/shifting stuff goes in here
#
# Code for updating catalyst (goes inside interation loop)
if catalyst < catalyst_reset:
    catalyst += 1
elif catalyst >= catalyst_reset:
    catalyst = 0
    catalyst_reset += 1
```

(reverseWordSentence function you see in the code):

```
def reverseWordSentence(Sentence):
 
    # Splitting the Sentence into list of words.
    words = Sentence.split(" ")
     
    # Reversing each word and creating
    # a new list of words
    # List Comprehension Technique
    newWords = [word[::-1] for word in words]
     
    # Joining the new list of words
    # for a new Sentence
    newSentence = " ".join(newWords)
 
    return newSentence
```

I tried using and tinkering with code from websites like [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/caesar-cipher-in-cryptography/) and other websites but they ended up shifting the whole string by one amount, not shifting in two directions, doing some other weirdness, or a combination of those. I tried making my own system to no avail. I'm out of ideas. Maybe I'm missing something big but I am not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets start with writing a function for encrypting a letter:

```
import string

letters = string.ascii_uppercase

def encrypt(letter, catalyst, is_odd):
    letter_index = ord(letter) - ord("A")
    new_letter_index = letter_index - catalyst if is_odd else letter_index + catalyst
    return letters[new_letter_index]
```

Now it should be easy to use it correctly:

```
is_odd = True
encrypted = []
for character in new_mtbe_one:
    # iterating over string iterates over every character
    if character == " ":
        is_odd = True
        encrypted.append(" ")
        continue
    encrypted.append(encrypt(character, catalyst, is_odd))
    is_odd = not is_odd
    # catalyst stuff
```

In case to make it work with digits we need to improve slightly `encrypt` function:

```
digits = string.digits

def encrypt(letter, catalyst, is_odd):
    value = ord("0") if letter.isdigit() else ord("A")
    letter_index = ord(letter) - value
    new_letter_index = letter_index - catalyst if is_odd else letter_index + catalyst
    return digits[new_letter_index] if letter.isdigit() else letters[new_letter_index]
```

BONUS: Instead of getting day number from the input, you could get it from the current date:

```
def day_of_week():
    return date.today().strftime("%w")
```

Comment: It works perfectly when the message is converted to capital letters (thanks a ton btw), however it kind of has  an existential crisis when I try to put in numbers, what can I do to shift numbers and keep them numbers? (HELLO THERE123 became MOHJB mmiHNJBa)

Thanks!

Comment: You need to do similar trick as with letters. What can be usefull for you - `string.digits`, `if letter.isdigit()` and `ord("0")`. Try to join that pieces and in case of problems let me know.

Comment: I tinkered around with it for a while but I couldn't get it to work right. At least I discovered a bunch of new errors I never knew existed! I think I got most of it right except for the last part where it returned the new indexes... Otherwise.. everything works perfectly! (thanks a ton again)

Comment: Edited an answer, hope it solves your problem!

Comment: Alright, noticed a few strange issues... Number shifting works great when the message is only one number, but adding more numbers has strange effects, like catalyst 0 "123" becomes "313" instead of "115". I also noticed that trying to encrypt long strings (especially with catalyst 1, 2, and 3) results in an "string index out of range" error. If I try to do "never gonna give" in catalyst 1, 2, and 3, it gives me the error, but this error does not occur in other catalysts. "never gonna give you up" gives me the error in almost every catalyst except for 0 and 6. I have no idea why any of this is.

Comment: "123" after backwarding becomes "321", so "313" sound like a correct result. I think this topic expanded too much, feel free to ask new question with your currect code, examples and expected/your output